# Are there any comic book authoring programs?

Tags: software-rec, images

Is there any software for creating comic books? The basic features needed are pre-drawn frames around the panels and the ability to easily drag and drop characters into the scene, add speech bubbles, and edit the background. I would prefer software that is specific to these tasks, rather than general graphic-editing software.

Comment: [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), maybe?  [Here's a tutorial](http://thepinksylphide.com/category/computer/software/inkscape) that could get you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Radical Comic Designer](http://lunduke.com/?page_id=3012)  He charges for packages but you can download the source from git and build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[TBO](http://www.getdeb.net/software/tbo) can do this, although it hasn't been updated in awhile.

[image: tbo screenshot]

It isn't available from the official Ubuntu repositories but can be installed from [GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net/software/tbo)